# Adding new rows to dataframe subsets using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Customer ProductID Count

John     1         25
John     6         50
Mary     2         15
Mary     3         35
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
Customer ProductID Count

John     1         25
John     2         0
John     3         0
John     6         50
Mary     1         0
Mary     2         15
Mary     3         35
Mary     6         0
```

What I am trying to do is identifying unique `ProductID` from the dataframe

```
unique_ID =  pd.unique(df.ProductID.ravel())
print (unique_ID) = array([1,6,2,3])
```

Since `ProductID` 2,3 are not present for Customer John, I will split the dataframe by Customer name

```
df1 = df[df['Customer']=='John']
df2 = df[df['Customer']=='Mary']
```

print df1

```
Customer  ProductID  Count
John      1          25
John      6          50
```

print df2

```
Customer  ProductID  Count
Mary      2          15
Mary      3          35
```

I would like to add `ProductID` 2,3 to John and `ProductID` 1,6 to Mary and set `Count` to 0 for these `ProductID` as shown in my desired output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) - you get `NaN` values which are [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `0` and last need original shape of `df` - use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='Customer',columns='ProductID', values='Count')
         .fillna(0)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='Count'))
  Customer  ProductID  Count
0     John          1   25.0
1     John          2    0.0
2     John          3    0.0
3     John          6   50.0
4     Mary          1    0.0
5     Mary          2   15.0
6     Mary          3   35.0
7     Mary          6    0.0
```

Another solution - first get [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of columns ([`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) of column `ProductID`), then create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df` by this `Multiindex`:

```
a = df.Customer.unique()
b = df.ProductID.sort_values().unique()

print (a)
['John' 'Mary']
print (b)
[1 2 3 6]

m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b])
print (m)
MultiIndex(levels=[['John', 'Mary'], [1, 2, 3, 6]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]])

df1 = df.set_index(['Customer','ProductID']).reindex(m, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Customer','ProductID','Count']
print (df1)
  Customer  ProductID  Count
0     John          1     25
1     John          2      0
2     John          3      0
3     John          6     50
4     Mary          1      0
5     Mary          2     15
6     Mary          3     35
7     Mary          6      0
```